# Instantaneous code is delayed? Is Task used correctly?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, async-await, task

So I finished some coding but I did not understand some of the outcomes that happened. I will try to write some gibberish code here that is very similar to the real code I have. If this information is important: It is an UWP app.

One method I will use that will be named`textBlockTextMethod()` is a method with a bunch of `if` and `if-else` statements that will always end up in giving `textBlock.Text` a new text (in this example let it always be `"End"`).

So first let's take a look at how my code looked first:

```
private void DoSomething()
{
textBlock.Text = "Start";
aIntVal = aMethod(); //aIntVal being a `int` variable
textBlockTextMethod();
}

private int aMethod()
{
int anotherIntVal = 0;


 for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
  {
  anotherIntVal += randomNum; // randomNum being a random 'int' value
  }

return anotherIntVal
}
```

What did I expect from it? I wanted `textBlock.Text` to have the text `"Start"` so I could visually see `Start` in the UWP app. Then `aIntVal` should receive an `int` value from `aMethod()`. `aMethod()` takes about 2-3 seconds to finish and after that `textBlock.Text` should have another value from `textBlockTextMethod`.

What happened here though is that the `TextBlock` would not show the text `Start`. The UWP app would freeze for 2 seconds and then I would see `End` in the UWP app that has been set in `textBlockTextMethod()`.

**Why is it so that I couldn't see `Start`?** I though it would be visible during the duration of the freeze. But like this it feels like `aMethod` is called before `Start` is set to `textBlock.Text` (or rather `Start` is never set to `textBlock.Text`)

Then I tried something different. This is my second try on the code:

```
private async void DoSomething()
{
Task<string> aTask = taskMethod()
textBlock.Text = await aTask;
aIntVal = aMethod();
textBlockTextMethod();
}

private async Task<string> taskMethod()
{
textBlock.Text = "Start";
await Task.Delay(1);
return "";
}

private int aMethod()
{
int anotherIntVal = 0;


 for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
  {
  anotherIntVal += randomNum();
  }

return anotherIntVal
}
```

This allowed me to see `Start` in the UWP app during the freeze. But it wasn't very consistent. Most of the time I could see `Start`. But a few times I had the same problem as before that `Start` was not shown.

I noticed that changing `Task.Delay(1)` to `Task.Delay(100)` would show me `Start` consistent. **Why is that so?**

Now this is the third try of my code that I use right now:

```
private async void DoSomething()
{
textBlock.Text = "Start";
aIntVal = await aMethod();
textBlockTextMethod();
}

private async Task<int> aMethod()
{
int anotherIntVal = 0;

await Task.Run(() =>
 {
 for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
  {
  anotherIntVal += randomNum();
  }
 });
return anotherIntVal
}
```

My question here: **Is my solution used correctly?** It works. But is it because I was just lucky here and this only works in some cases or is it the usual way to go on how to use `Task`, `async` and `await`?

Comment: **Pro Tip**, most of the people who look at this read and write code for a living, we like to see it formatted well so we don't have to squint to work out what lumps of code are doing, in short its helps us help you

Comment: You execute aMethod in the UI thread. UI thread is supposed to show you `"Start"`, the `Text` is set, but UI thread is busy to run your `aMethod`. that's why it freeze, with Task.Delay you give it a time to do something briefly, but thats not the right way. you should use Task.Run instead to execute `aMethod` in another thread.

Comment: `await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false);` may also work but thats still not the right way. use `Task.Run` instead

Comment: " I will try to write some gibberish code here that is very similar " - but have you verified that this code *exhibits the same behaviour that you're asking about*? We much prefer a [mcve]

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary So 'aMethod' is blocking the UI thread. But before the UI thread gets blocked I set 'textBlock.Text' to "Start". How should I imagine the flow here? 'textblock.Text' receives the value 'Start' but before it can visualize it 'aMethode' is called?

Comment: yes, when UI thread returns from `DoSomething`, then it can do other stuff it should do like updating the layout etc. if your method takes long time to run then UI thread cant return to do its job so it freeze. when you do `await Task` inside `DoSomething` it means UI can return from `DoSomething` while `Task` is running on separate thread. so both threads can do what they should do simultaneously. when `Task` is finished, UI thread will come back to continue execution of `DoSomething` right from where it left at `await Task`.

Comment: now if you add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` UI thread wont necessarily come back to continue the execution of `DoSomething`, it can be any other thread to continue executing whats after `await task.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to free up the *UI* for a *CPU bound* workload, you can do something like this

```
// async task
private async void ButtonClick()
{
   // update the text box
   textBlock.Text = "Start";

   // if we have to wrap some CPU work, dont do it in the implementation
   // use task run to call it.
   // So... lets do something on the thread pool
   // await the results, giving back the ui thread
   var aIntVal = await Task.Run(() => aMethod()); 
   // continue back on the UI thread and update the text box again
   textBlock.Text = aIntVal;
}

// Vanilla method to do stuff
private int aMethod()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
       // awesome calculations here
   return anotherIntVal;
}
```

---

**Additional Resources**

Read everything by *Stephen Cleary*

Start here [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)